# "Module loading did not complete" without circular deps in requirejs

Tags: gruntjs, requirejs, r.js

[edit] I narrowed the issue to the lib three.js. The application does work, what doesn't work is the r.js optimizer, when I remove all references to three.js in my require process then r.js does the compiling ( but then the app is not working anymore )

I simply comment those shims where I reference the lib as dep. those libs are still required so they are not the problem. it's the `render/three` that is problematic. However I can't see why for now

```
   "render/OrbitControls": ["render/three"],
    "render/TrackballControls": ["render/three"],
    "render/Detector": ["render/three"],
    "render/stats.min": ["render/three"],
    "render/threex.rendererstats": ["render/three"],
    "render/ColladaLoader": ["render/three"],
    "render/Projector": ["render/three"],
```

[ original ]
I doubled checked circular deps manually and with Madge in my requirejs project.

However even with those precautions r.js keeps saying me that it can't complete module loading. I'm a bit stuck here

Here is a screen of what's happening in the console.

[image]

And here is my r.js config in grunt

```
    requirejs: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    name:           "engine",
                    baseUrl:        "./src/GuildEngine/",
                    mainConfigFile: "./src/GuildEngine/engine.js",
                    out:            "./build/www/data/curry.min.js",
                    optimize:       "uglify2",

                    preserveLicenseComments: false,
                    generateSourceMaps:      true,
                    findNestedDependencies:  true,

                    uglify2: {
                        sourceRoot: "../../src/GuildEngine",
                        mangle:     {
                            toplevel:  true,
                            screw_ie8: true
                        },
                        wrap:       "",
                        compress:   {
                            sequences:    true,
                            dead_code:    true,
                            conditionals: true,
                            booleans:     true,
                            unused:       true,
                            if_return:    true,
                            join_vars:    true,
                            //drop_console: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved the issue by effectively removing the dependencies to three.js in the shim configuration. What works is to add a require call wrapping the require call of the other libraries. This is the only way I found for both r.js and my app to work.

This :

    `require(["render/three"], function(){
      require(["render/ColladaLoader"], function(){ ... });
    });`

instead of : 
`"render/ColladaLoader": ["render/three"]` and : `require(["render/ColladaLoader"], function(){ ... });`